# Adding Android Library to Existing Project on Android Studio 0.3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to add a library, https://github.com/edmodo/cropper, to my Android project. I am following the methods described here: [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

but the Android Studio has changed since then and I can no longer "Import a Module". I can only add a new one. Here are the steps I have tried:

Copy the library into a folder named libraries.
[image: project structure before adding module]

Open Module Settings, and I am presented with this screen
[image: module settings]

I click the + sign to add a new module and am then presented with this screen
[image: first add new module step]

I choose to fill in the content root
[image: content root select]

The rest of the fields autofill to this
[image: autofill]

The next step...
[image: next step]

I change the package
[image]

I hit next and now my project looks like this
[image: project structure after new module added]

Any idea on the correct way to add an external library in Android Studio 0.3.6+?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use the wizard. Usually I edit the gradle files.

Create a structure like this:

```
- Blunka
    build.gradle
- cropper
    build.gradle
    src
    res
  settings.gradle
```

In settings.gradle:

```
include ':Blunka', ':cropper'
```

In cropper/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {

   compileSdkVersion 19
   buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion XX
       targetSdkVersion 19

   }    

   sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']            
                res.srcDirs = ['res']            
            }
        }
    }
```

In Blunka/build.gradle add:

```
dependencies {
    // Libraries
    compile project(':cropper')  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am doing this, but when i go to import something in the src folder of cropper, it cannot find the class. The package path does resolve however. There is a red circle in the project structure view of the file I want to import...

Comment: EDIT: I marked the src directory in cropper as a source root, and the little red circle went away, but it still cannot resolve the symbol.

Comment: @clocksmith did this ever work for you? Any suggestions?